# Finite type ring extension + condition = finite extension?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Is the following true ?

> If $A \subset B$ is finite type extension (i.e. $B$ is a finitely generated $A$-algebra) of integral domains such that the set $\{\mathfrak q\in\operatorname{Spec}B\mid\mathfrak q\cap A=(0)\}$ is finite. Does this imply that $B$ is a finitely generated $A$-module ?

Comment: Have you checked the case that $A$ is a field?

Comment: Yes, I can prove it when $A$ is a field, but this proof does not work for the general case.

Comment: If you localize at $S = A - \{0\}$, you get that $S^{-1} B$ is a finitely generated extension of a field $S^{-1} A$, so as you have proved a finite dimensional vector space. Maybe the basis of $S^{-1} B$ as an $S^{-1} A$ vector space (which we can take as a subset of $B$) will lift to generators of $B$ as an $A$-module.

Comment: The answer is no: consider $A=\mathbb Q[x,y]$ and $B=\mathbb Q[x,y,x/y]\subset \mathbb Q(x,y)$. Geometrically, you have a generically finite morphism of integral algebraic varieties, and you ask whether the morphism is finite. There are plenty of counterexamples when the target variety has dimension $\ge 2$.

Comment: And why are comment boxes used for answers?